# Does armour take damage when you fall?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As of Minecraft 1.0, does armour take damage when you fall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, armour does not get damaged from falling. This is tested in this video.

Comment: What good is Protection then?  I thought environmental damage *was* fall damage.

Comment: @John Protection does reduce your damage, but not effect durability, I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Armor in Minecraft is not damaged from any fall of any height, unless the boots are enchanted with Feather Falling I, II or III.

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.0, maybe not.  But in beta 1.6/7, falling did damage armor, as it will damage life points.

Answer (score 0):

Protection protects from fall damage, but doesn't reduce armor durability when doing so. Otherwise, protection would wear down armor more quickly.

Answer (score -1):

In the later Minecraft betas, armor has its own health bar, so when you fall it will take a chunk from 1 of the 4 armor categories.